# Does Gaussian Naive Bayes have paramter to be tuned

Tags: machine-learning, probability, naivebayes, hyperparameters

I am trying to implement the Gaussian Naive Bayes from a scikit-learn library. I know that the Naive Bayes is based on the Bayes' theorem which is defined in high level as:
`posterior = (prior * likelihood) / evidence.`

As far as I know, the prior and evidence are learned from the training data.

I am not sure about likelihood whether Q1: is it also learned from the training data or by using *Maximum likelihood estimation* ?. Q2: Is there any hyper-parameter required to be tuned or not ?.

Comment: This question is better suited for [statistics.se]

Comment: Thanks, @juanpa.arrivillaga for sharing this website. I will ask the question there.

Comment: For the future, please keep in mind that [cross-posting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/481189/does-gaussian-naive-bayes-have-paramter-to-be-tuned_) verbatim questions at more than one SE sites is [not allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Suppose you have  Bayes Theorem as,

```
P(A|B) = (P(B|A)*P(A))/P(B)
Where,
P(A|B) = Posterior Probability
P(B|A) = Likelihood
P(A) = Prior Probability
P(B) = Marginal Likelihood
```

**Answers to Your Question**

1. Likelihood is calculated using the training data, and the Maximum Likelihood estimation is used to calculated the maximum value of the likelihood.
2. Naive Bayes has almost no hyperparameters to tune, so it usually generalizes well.

Comment: Please do **not** include pleads for accepting/upvoting in the post itself (edited out). Moreover, notice that the privilege of voting up is earned at 15 rep points, i.e. OP here has not yet reached it.